# Namespace treated as type

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, cmake

I have two files Collider.h and Collidable.h, organized this way :

```
Folder 1:
----Collider.h
----Folder 2:
--------Collidable.h
```

here's the files content :
`Collidable.h`

```
#pragma once


#include "../Collider.h"

namespace nsInterfaces
{
    class Collidable
    {

    public:
        nsEngine::Collider * col {nullptr};
    public:
        virtual bool collides (const Collidable & other) const noexcept = 0;
        virtual ~Collidable () { delete col; }

    };
}



typedef std::unique_ptr<nsInterfaces::Collidable>   uptCollidable;
typedef std::shared_ptr<nsInterfaces::Collidable>   sptCollidable;
typedef std::vector<sptCollidable>                  CollidableVector;
```

And `Collider.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "../Utility/Typedef.hpp"
#include "../Utility/GameException.h"

#include "Movement.h"

namespace nsEngine
{
    class Collider
    {
    /**/
    private:
    public:

        Collider () {}
        virtual ~Collider () noexcept {}

        virtual Collider * clone () noexcept = 0;
    protected:
        float x;
        float y;
        /**/
    };
}
```

I'm developping a game for myself, as you could expect, but i keep on getting the same error :

```
error: 'nsEngine' does not name a type
     nsEngine::Collider * col {nullptr};
     ^
```

And of course `error: "col" was not declared in this scope`

I'm using cmake and mingw w64 (GCC 4.9.1 i believe). I know i might not give enough information, so ask me !

Thank you for reading.

Comment: PS : if I turn the two concerned lines to comments, my code gets built.

Comment: The problem seems to be somewhere in the rest of the code to be honest. You could try writing `::nsEngine::Collider` instead and see if it helps.

Comment: Well, that doesn't change anything, was worth a try.
I tried creating a "aaatest" class in my main.cpp, and making a public <code>nsEngine::Collider * a;</code> member variable, it works ... Maybe it has to see with the ".." in the include ...

Comment: Ye, that would be my second thought - that some other file is included. To test this theory, the simplest way is to just rename your header to something else...

Comment: @AlanStokes had a good idea. In that case, you can try something like `class nsEngine::Collider * col {nullptr};`

Comment: I'm actually changing to `#pragma once` (because nicer to use), it might be the problem. I just tried to put the good old #ifndef method, but won't work either. Still, it works when i call it from somewhere else.

Comment: @AlanStockes you were right when you said it was a circular include problem. But, no reason to bypass pragma and/or (yeah, and/or) ifndef/define/endif ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a buggy problem of circular include, bypassing `#pragma once` and/or `#ifndef/#define#endif`

Can't find the reason for that though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your problem under my environment (Windows/Visual studio) and I do not have this problem. The only error I had is some `Impossible to open the source file ../Collider.h` if it is not in the build path (even if `collidable.h` is), and in that case the same `'ncEngine' does not name a type` error.

I did notice that you include all you files using relative path from the current file. E.g.: `../Utility/GameException.h`... Why don't you rather use path related to your project root directory and include files like this:

```
#include "Engine/collider.h"
#include "Engine/Interface/collidable.h"
#include "Utility/GameException.h"
```

This will may not fix your problem, but it does in my Win/Visual environment and (in my opinion) makes the code more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with MINGW and g++ 5.1 and I could actually reproduce the error, I got it when I forgot to put a # in front of `pragma once`.  If I put the # in front it builds correctly so it was just happenstance that I saw it. It seems to have nothing to do with the includes relative paths so it is like the pragma once doesn't work.

I would suggest try putting `#ifndef/#define/#endif` guards instead of using `#pragma once.`

Comment: It compiles if I call it from somewhere else, as long as I comment the members. I tried replacing all the pragmas, didn't work.